# Distribute columns evenly in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have my window set to `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and in my window there is a row of controls that I want to define the width of the window. Underneath those controls I would like a DataGrid with three columns.

However I can't seem to evenly distribute the three columns so that they are the same size and use the space available. Is there a way to do this in C#.NET?

Comment: set `Width="*"` on DataGridColumns

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak When I do that the columns just shoot of the window! I think because of the `SizeToContent` property.

Comment: that means, that container which contains your DataGrid does not have a fixed Width.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak I'm aware of this because I need the DataGrid to fill the width of the window, which is sized depending on the content. I wondered if there was any code I could use the resize the columns once the window is loaded so I know the size of the window, which I can then just divide by 3

Comment: Possible duplication of [WPF DataGrid Column Width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947131/wpf-datagrid-column-width)

Comment: @Sheridan It's not, because I've tried the answer on that question, and there was no suggestion that the OP was using `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via DataBinding. For example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="panel">
        <Label Content="1" Width="90"/>
        <Label Content="2" Width="90"/>
        <Label Content="3" Width="90"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <DataGrid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=panel}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to be working. Would it be because I have not specified the widths of the controls in the panel the width is binded too?

Comment: No. You can compile this example and remove `Width="90"` from `Label`s. It will still work. If it doesn't work for you, again, that means that some outer container is setting `Width` to `*` or that one of the controls in the first row has a `Width` set to `*` (or both). If you cant seem to locate where exactly it happens, you can use Snoop to debug this issue.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak- What happens if the outer container's `Width` is set to `*`?

Comment: @Andrew, as i recall, the `DataGrid` will stretch infinitely then.